# Rendering View to string performance

Tags: string, asp.net-mvc-4

I have built an app that renders mvc views into strings and uses HiQPDF to render a PDF report. This works well, however, repeated calls to IView.Render causes considerable performance degredation. Each call takes about 1s longer than the previous call - and the html being rendered is nearly the same.

Anyone know of other ways to render html that does not take this kind of performance hit? Anyone know why I'm seeing such bad performance with this code?

```
protected string RenderViewToStringInternal(string viewPath, object model,
                                                    bool partial = false,
                                                    string master = null)
        {
            //Find cached view 
            ViewEngineResult viewEngineResult = _cachedViews.ContainsKey(viewPath) ? _cachedViews[viewPath] : null;

            if (viewEngineResult == null)
            {
                //Get view engine result
                if (partial)
                    viewEngineResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(Context, viewPath);
                else
                    viewEngineResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(Context, viewPath, master);

                if (viewEngineResult != null)
                {
                    _cachedViews.Add(viewPath, viewEngineResult);
                }
            }

            if (viewEngineResult == null)
                throw new FileNotFoundException("View not found");

            // get the view and attach the model to view data
            var view = viewEngineResult.View;

            Context.Controller.ViewData.Model = model;

            string result = null;

            using (var sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                var ctx = new ViewContext(Context, view,
                                            Context.Controller.ViewData,
                                            Context.Controller.TempData,
                                            sw);

                DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
                **view.Render(ctx, sw);** //This line's performance degrades after subsequent calls with similar data
                DateTime end = DateTime.Now;

                Logging.LogInformation(Logging.TraceType.UI, string.Format("ViewRenderer.RenderViewToStringInternal view.Render execution time: {0}", end.Subtract(start).TotalSeconds));

                viewEngineResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(Context, view);

                result = sw.ToString();
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: could be some kind of locking, is the view doing anything it shouldnt and performing calculations or accessing files? Try rendering the view from a controller and returning the html multiple times and see if that also has the slow down

Comment: I've tested through the controller (via rendering all of the report pages via partials). Executing this over and over (refreshing the page in a browser) shows very good performance. Each page load remains a constant .5 seconds. Whereas after 10 or 20 renderings using the code above can take over 60 seconds for a small portion of the report...

Comment: I should add - this does not occurr on my development laptop with the same sample data. This only happens on our development and staging servers (Im assuming its going to occurr in production as well).

Comment: I just tested using a standard MVC view - the login page that comes out of the box with MVC. This view also has this horrid performance after calling it 20 or so times.

Comment: So to summarize, the performance of this method was only terrible on our dev and staging servers which happened to be virtual servers. On native hardware this performance issue does not exist. To get around this issue and guarantee performance on all servers, I refactored the code to make web requests for partial views. This proved to be very performant and scalable (html rendering is subsecond per page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in my comments to my own question - this issue only occurred in a virtual environment. I never determined why this code ran slow, however to resolve my performance issue I changed my code to retrieve each of the PDF pages via separate web requests that rendered individual MVC partials. This dramatically increased throughput and the resulting requests took less than 100ms.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following to render views to strings and have not seen any of the issues you describe

```
public static class ContollerContextExtensions
    {
        /// <remarks>If you have any validation summaries they will not be populated by this method</remarks>
        public static string RenderPartialToString(this ControllerContext ControllerContext, string viewName, object model)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
                viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
            ViewDataDictionary ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary();
            TempDataDictionary TempData = new TempDataDictionary();
            ViewData.Model = model;

            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
                ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
                viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

                return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ControllerContext"></param>
        /// <param name="viewName"></param>
        /// <param name="model"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        /// <remarks>If you have any validation summaries they will not be populated by this method</remarks>
        public static string RenderViewToString(this ControllerContext ControllerContext, string viewName, object model, string masterName = null)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
                viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
            ViewDataDictionary ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary();
            TempDataDictionary TempData = new TempDataDictionary();
            ViewData.Model = model;

            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(ControllerContext, viewName, masterName);
                ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
                viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

                return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you repeatedly call this method in a single web request? In my scenario, I render the views to html up to 100 times in a single web request. The first calls are quick, but every request takes about 1s longer than the previous. To make things more annoying, this only happens on our dev / staging servers which are virtual. This does not happen on my intel i7 development laptop.

Comment: So, 1 web request from a client invokes an action on my controller. This action then calls my render to html method up to 100 times. Each time takes about a second more than the previous. Subsequent web requests from a client 'resets' the performance issue - the first couple view to html renderings are quick and then they start to degrade about 1s per call...very strange

Comment: Yes within one request I am calling this quite a bit at least 100 times as you mention, the biggest slow down I notice is the HTML to PDF converter itself

Comment: Is the view aye try a memory/performance profiling tool to get an even better idea